# Link Ubuntu armhf libraries libxcb.so.1 and libXdmcp.so.6

Tags: linux, ubuntu, arm, beagleboard, toolchain

I am trying to build application on omap3 beagleboard with armhf Ubuntu using toolchain arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++. The problem is that I cannot find in any armhf ubuntu distro (neither oficial ubuntu neither beagleboard) libraries libxcb.so.1 and libXdmcp.so.6. Does anybody had this issue before?

/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libXau.so.6, needed by /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libxcb.so.1, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libXdmcp.so.6, needed by /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libxcb.so.1, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)

Comment: Take a look at this [article](http://www.lshift.net/blog/2012/06/17/using-debian-multiarch-for-cross-compiling), that shows how to setup multiarch support in Debian.